# How to use django-compressor with apache?

Tags: django, apache, django-compressor

I'm been using Django Compressor to manage my coffee/less files and its great for development, but I've had some issues to make it work for my production deployment.

My idea is to have apache to host the static files, possibly in another server. I'm setting `COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True` on the `settings.py` file.

Then I do the following

- `python manage.py compress` - This populates the `CACHE` directory in my `static` directory, where all static files will be collected.
- `python manage.py collectstatic` - This collects static files from all the apps on my project (some of which don't use compressor) into my `static` directory.
- Copy the `static` directory somewhere to be hosted with apache. And setup apache to serve the files.
- Modify the `static_url` variable in the `settings.py` file to point to the static server.

If I open any page, I get the following error on my server, this only seems to happen when I have `DEBUG = False` and `COMPRESS_OFFLINE = True` on my `settings.py` file:

> TemplateSyntaxError: Caught OfflineGenerationError while rendering:
>   You have offline compression enabled but key
>   "777ba26736d046ab043dc151e7e9a060" is missing from offline manifest.
>   You may need to run "python manage.py compress".

When I check the `static/CACHE` directory, I confirm what the error says, this is my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "6189b8598993d1cbdbd35d4dfd1a6711": "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://192.168.1.123/CACHE/js/2f6ca6616bd6.js\"></script>",
  "5c66dbed0e5b766c6e32773cd8585f3c": "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://192.168.1.123/CACHE/css/154d95903951.css\" type=\"text/css\" />"
}
```

If I delete the CACHE directory and rerun `python manage.py compress`, I get a new set of ID's both on the error message and the manifest file, but the ID on the error is still missing on the manifest.

So, I guess there are two questions here. Why is it not working? What is the proper way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have compressor's finder in `STATICFILES_FINDERS` in settings?

Comment: Please show your template code where you use the `{% compress %}` tag, that would help debugging the `TemplateSyntaxError` :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you've run compress, and you still get the message

> OfflineGenerationError: You have offline compression enabled but key "4971a40e3b459a8cda8287a7f7caa96d" is missing from offline manifest.  You may need to run "python manage.py compress"

then it's likely you have dynamic content inside compress tags.  Make sure that compress is always the innermost block, and that there are no tags inside the compress block.

Comment: To future people from Google: having dynamic content inside compress tags (for example `{% compress css %}{% if bootstrap %}`) can cause the OfflineGenerationError in all sorts of weird ways – including only for some users of your site even though they should get served the same templates! I initially disregarded this answer because my situation only applied to some users, but that was at my own peril. This was the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're using django-compressor 1.1.2 which doesn't support static template tag {% static "..." %}.

Try installing the dev version of django-compressor with:

> pip install django_compressor==dev

It should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

David Wolfe is absolutely right: had to dig throught all the code of mine to get rid of {% trans... etc.
I make it like this:

```
<script>
window.__enter_email = "{% trans "Enter correct email" %}"
window.__url = "{% url "shop:go" %}"
</script>
{% compress js %}
<script>
$("#bla")..... window.__enter_email ...
</script>
{% endcompress %}
```

Hope, helps someone!

Comment: Thanks, I marked David's response as accepted. I have not tested it (I haven't worked on this for years), but based on the upvotes and your comment it seems to be the good solution.